# Find closest or higher values in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table:

table1

```
rank  value
1     10
25    120
29    130
99    980
```

I have to generate the following table:

table2

```
rank  value
1     10
2     10
3     10
4     10
5     10
6     10
7     10
8     10
9     10
10    10
11    10
12    10
13    120
14    120
15    120
.
.
.
.
25    120
26    120
27    130
28    130
29    130
30    130
.
.
.
.
.
62    980
63    980
.
.
.
99    980
100   980
```

So, table2 should have all values from 1 to 100. There are 3 cases:

- If it's an exact match, for ex. rank 25, value would be 120
- Find closest, for ex. for rank 9 in table2, we do NOT have exact match, but 1 is closest to 9 (9-1 = 8 whereas 25-9 = 16), so assign value of 1
- If there is equal distribution from both sides, use higher rank value, for ex. for rank 27, we have 25 as well as 29 which are equally distant, so take higher value which is 29 and assign value.

Comment: I don't understand why this question is down voted?

Comment: If I understand well, your expected result for 62 and 63 should be 130, while the first number to give 980 should be 64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like

```
-- your testdata
with table1(rank,
value) as
 (select 1, 10
    from dual
  union all
  select 25, 120
    from dual
  union all
  select 29, 130
    from dual
  union all
  select 99, 980
    from dual),
-- range 1..100
data(rank) as
 (select level from dual connect by level <= 100)

select d.rank,
       min(t.value) keep(dense_rank first order by abs(t.rank - d.rank) asc, t.rank desc)
  from table1 t, data d
 group by d.rank;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cross join. Use the below query to get your result:

```
select t1.* from table1 t1 
cross join
(select * from table1) t2
on (t1.rank=t2.rank);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well your need, you could use the following:

```
select num, value
from (
        select num, value, row_number() over (partition by num order by abs(num-rank) asc, rank desc) as rn
        from table1
          cross join ( select level as num from dual connect by level <= 100) numbers
     )
where rn = 1
```

This joins your table with the [1,100] interval and then keeps only the first row for each number, ordering by the difference and keeping, in case of equal difference, the greatest value.

Answer (score 0):

Join hierarchical number generator with your table and use `lag()` with `ignore nulls` clause:

```
select h.rank, case when value is null 
                    then lag(value ignore nulls) over (order by h.rank) 
                    else value 
               end value
  from (select level rank from dual connect by level <= 100) h 
  left join t on h.rank = t.rank
  order by h.rank
```

Test:

```
with t(rank, value) as ( 
                        select  1,  10 from dual union all
                        select 25, 120 from dual union all
                        select 29, 130 from dual union all 
                        select 99, 980 from dual )
select h.rank, case when value is null 
                    then lag(value ignore nulls) over (order by h.rank) 
                    else value 
               end value
  from (select level rank from dual connect by level <= 100) h 
  left join t on h.rank = t.rank
  order by h.rank

      RANK       RANK
---------- ----------
         1         10
         2         10
...
        24         10
        25        120
        26        120
        27        120
        28        120
        29        130
        30        130
...
        98        130
        99        980
       100        980
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative that doesn't need a cross join (but does use a couple of analytic functions, so you'd need to test whether this is more performant for your set of data than the other solutions):

```
WITH sample_data AS (SELECT 1 rnk, 10 VALUE FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 25 rnk, 120 VALUE FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 29 rnk, 130 VALUE FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 99 rnk, 980 VALUE FROM dual)
SELECT rnk + LEVEL - 1 rnk,
       CASE WHEN rnk + LEVEL - 1 < rnk + (next_rank - rnk)/2 THEN
                 VALUE
            ELSE next_value
       END VALUE
FROM   (SELECT rnk,
               VALUE,
               LEAD(rnk, 1, 100 + 1) OVER (ORDER BY rnk) next_rank,
               LEAD(VALUE, 1, VALUE) OVER (ORDER BY rnk) next_value
        FROM   sample_data)
CONNECT BY PRIOR rnk = rnk
           AND PRIOR sys_guid() IS NOT NULL
           AND LEVEL <= next_rank - rnk;

       RNK      VALUE
---------- ----------
         1         10
         2         10
       ...        ...
        12         10
        13        120
       ...        ...
        24        120
        25        120
        26        120
        27        130
        28        130
        29        130
        30        130
       ...        ...
        63        130
        64        980
        65        980
       ...        ...
        98        980
        99        980
       100        980
```

N.B, I'm not sure why you have 62 and 63 as having a value of 980 - the mid point between 29 and 99 is 64.

Also, you'll see that I've used `100 + 1` instead of `101` - this is because if you wanted to parameterise things, you would replace `100` with the parameter - e.g. `v_max_rank + 1`